# Vuetify v-dialog not covering fully the parent page when showed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've a `v-dialog` to show a form inside a main page, that's contains a `v-data-table`. When the `v-dialog` is opened, the DOM parent's content keeping showed on the `v-dialog`. I desire that `v-dialog` opens and hiddes full main page until closed. On the second print the content being displayed in the dialog becomes clear.

**v-dialog**

```
  <template>
      <div style="background-color: white;">
        <v-dialog scrollable fullscreen v-model="show" style="background-color: white; width: 800px;" persistent>
                <v-tabs fixed-tabs>
        <v-tab>Único</v-tab>
        <v-tab>Vários</v-tab>
            <v-tab-item>
            </v-tab-item>
            <v-tab-item>
                <v-layout style="height: 100%; background: white;"> 
                    <div style="height: 100%; background: green;">
                       <h1 style="width: 20px;" >asdsa</h1>
                       <h1>asd</h1>
                   </div>
                </v-layout>
          </v-tab-item>
    </v-dialog>
 </div>
</template>
```

**MainPage**

[image]

**Dialog**

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you have a reproduction link ? Since this is basically a CSS issue, it will be hard to help you without any dev tools or known properties. Even if it's just missing some `height: 100%` somewhere.

Comment: That have many business logic and far properties of particular data. But if cause can be it I can check all components.

Comment: You can either mock the data and keep it basic enough for it to work or yeah, basically inspect all of the components with the dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you put `v-tabs` directly into the `v-dialog` component. The `v-tabs` component changes its height based on the content thats inside it.
I suggest you wrap your tabs in a `v-card` and `v-card-text` component. With the `fullscreen` prop on the dialog the card will take the full height and obscure anything behind it. With your sample code it would look like this:

```html
<div style="background-color: white;">
  <v-dialog
    scrollable
    fullscreen
    v-model="show"
    style="background-color: white; width: 800px;"
    persistent
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-tabs fixed-tabs>
          <v-tab>Único</v-tab>
          <v-tab>Vários</v-tab>
          <v-tab-item>
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item>
            <v-layout style="height: 100%; background: white;">
              <div style="height: 100%; background: green;">
                <h1 style="width: 20px;">asdsa</h1>
                <h1>asd</h1>
              </div>
            </v-layout>
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</div>
```